# How to plot odds ratios on log scale in Python

Tags: python

Very new to Python and I want to know if its possible to plot odds ratios in python using a log scale on the x-axis. Any useful links or example code would be fantastic. The plots should come out looking something like this (SAS code) https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2015/07/29/or-plots-log-scale.html. There has to be some way to do this in Python. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

matplotlib is the goto plotting option in python. Many other frameworks exist for more complicated plotting, but matplotlib is the place to start.

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.semilogx.html#matplotlib.pyplot.semilogx

You don't give much information, but this should get you started:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]
plt.semilogx(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The plots need to come out looking something like this https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2015/07/29/or-plots-log-scale.html. I've been looking for example of these kinds of plots created using Python and to my surprise I haven't been able to find any. Most people seem to use R, SAS, or excel. I would imagine there some package for this in Python.

Comment: Those look like box and whisker plots: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pyplots/boxplot_demo_pyplot.html?highlight=boxplot

Comment: @A.Rod the python packages that do the things R and excel do are: scipy, numpy, pandas, matplotlib, and many others, as your needs get more complex.